# sed replace block of yaml code with nothing

Tags: sed

I am trying to use sed to remove a piece of code from a yaml file. what I have so far is the below code, but it does not work.

```
sed -i 's/- node-service\/velocity_log_deployment((.|\n)*)//' config.yml
```

the code that I want to remove is:

```
       - terraform/init_and_plan:
          name: terraform_plan
          context:
            - phdv-docker-hub-creds
            - phdv-aws
          terraform_version: <<pipeline.parameters.terraform_version>>
          working_directory: ~/project/infra
          persist_to_workspace_filepath_prefix: infra/
          requires:
            - package
# remove start
      - node-service/velocity_log_deployment:
          name: velocity_log_deployment
          repository_url: https://github.com/pizzahutuk/lambda-contentful-menu-sync
          requires:
            - terraform_apply
          context:
            - phdv-docker-hub-creds
            - phdv-aws
# remove end
      - terraform/init_and_apply:
          name: terraform_apply
          context:
            - phdv-docker-hub-creds
            - phdv-aws
          terraform_version: <<pipeline.parameters.terraform_version>>
          working_directory: ~/project/infra
          requires:
            - terraform_plan
          filters:
            branches:
              only: main
```

result after sed replace:

```
       - terraform/init_and_plan:
          name: terraform_plan
          context:
            - phdv-docker-hub-creds
            - phdv-aws
          terraform_version: <<pipeline.parameters.terraform_version>>
          working_directory: ~/project/infra
          persist_to_workspace_filepath_prefix: infra/
          requires:
            - package
      - terraform/init_and_apply:
          name: terraform_apply
          context:
            - phdv-docker-hub-creds
            - phdv-aws
          terraform_version: <<pipeline.parameters.terraform_version>>
          working_directory: ~/project/infra
          requires:
            - terraform_plan
          filters:
            branches:
              only: main
```

Comment: Your YAML seems to be partial. What are the sections that you have deleted? This array should probably be part of a structure, right?

Answer (score 2):

Honestly; this is terraform. That's a gigantic piece of software meant to help you deploy infrastructure through code; it uses a well-defined file format, YAML, for that job. So, keeping these files syntactically intact is pretty important.

Still you chose to use an inadequate tool for that language, `sed`, using regular expressions to parse a non-regular language, instead of a tool that actually "speaks the language".
The most correct approach here is to ignore what has been done using `sed` and just use, for example, if you're using [Kislyuk's `yq`](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/), it lets just `del`ete elements.

```
yq -y 'del(.[] | select(."node-service/velocity_log_deployment"))' config.yml
```

should do what you want. Add the `-i` switch to change the file in-place. Omit the `-y` if you're using the [Go `yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/).

Comment: My version of `yq` (4.32.2, updated from [github](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) just a couple of minutes ago) doesn't have `-y`. What does it do?

Comment: ah, sorry, there's actually two `yq`, @roaima. For [mine](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) it re-converts to yaml (it uses `jq` underneath). Y

Comment: Ah ok! For now I'm going to leave my first comment in place (I've added a link to the version I had) but I'll delete this one. Just acknowledging your comment, really! Thanks.

Comment: I'll try with yours as well

Comment: Gotcha. My version doesn't need to the `-y` flag at all

Comment: It's not terraform

Comment: Did you think maybe I don't want to have to install other tools and have other dependencies?

Comment: I did. That argument comes up **so** often... hence: my first paragraph. YAML is not a regular language, you literally can't parse all of YAML with sed, it's impossible. And even if you happen to have a subset of YAML for which you can, installing these tools is much easier than trying to deal with all the ways your regular expression can land face-first in the dust. So, really, nah, get over it and use proper tooling. There's also nothing wrong with just using python with `import yaml`, for example. But any software that deals with this type of data needs sofistication that `sed` doesn't have

Comment: ("it's impossible", "sophistication that `sed` doesn't have": these are results from math/theoretical computer science. It's not a "it's more effort than it'd be worth", it's a "the tool you have is provenly incapable of fulfilling the task, says math")